# Parametric Plot: different coordinates for texture and mesh

Tags: plotting, mesh, textures

I try to create a parametric plot which maps from the complex unit circle to a different region in the complex plane. That works fine but I have one problem:
I want to see the images of a mesh with respect to polar coordinates in the unit circle AND I want to map a picture embedded in the unit circle as a texture for the plot. The problem for me is, that if I parametrize the plot by polar coordinates, Mathematica uses the x- and y-axis of the image as angle/modulus-axes. Is there any way to use Cartesian Coordinates for the texture of the plot? Here is my code:

```
n = 6;
G[z_] := Exp[I Pi/4] NIntegrate[Power[(1 - (s)^n), -2/n], {s, 0, z},
   AccuracyGoal -> 2];

ParametricPlot[ReIm[G[x + I y]], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[],
  Mesh -> {10, 10},
PlotPoints -> {30, 30},
MaxRecursion -> 2,
PlotStyle -> {Opacity[1],
  Texture[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}]]}
 ]
```

[image: First code]

Result of the first code. I want the image to be this way but not the "cartesian" mesh.

```
n = 6;
G[z_] := Exp[I Pi/4] NIntegrate[Power[(1 - (s)^n), -2/n], {s, 0, z},
   AccuracyGoal -> 2];

ParametricPlot[ReIm[G[r Exp[I s]]], {r, 0, 1}, {s, 0, 2 Pi},
  Mesh -> {10, 10},
PlotPoints -> {30, 30},
MaxRecursion -> 2,
PlotStyle -> {Opacity[1],
  Texture[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}]]}
 ]
```

This code now gives the following picture (note that the only difference lies in the parametrization).

[image: Second code]

I would like to keep the mesh coming from polar coordinates in the second case and combine it with the cartesian texture from the first case.

I hope the formulation was understandable. Any advice is highly appreciated!

Comment: Please [edit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/253208/edit) your question to add the code you've tried. The code will help people to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lazy way to do it:

```
texture = Texture[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}]];

p1 = ParametricPlot[ReIm[G[x + I y]], {x, y} ∈ Disk[], 
  Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> {30, 30}, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], texture]];

p2 = ParametricPlot[ReIm[G[r Exp[I s]]], {r, 0, 1}, {s, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Mesh -> {10, 10}, PlotPoints -> {30, 30}, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
  PlotStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None];

Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

One way is using polar coordinate in mesh. `MeshFunctions -> {Norm[{#3, #4}] &, ArcTan[#3, #4] &}`. The other way need time to work out.

```
n = 6;
G[z_] = Exp[I Pi/4] Integrate[Power[(1 - (s)^n), -2/n], {s, 0, z}];
ParametricPlot[ReIm[G[x + I*y]], {x, y} ∈ Disk[], 
 Mesh -> {10, 10}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Norm[{#3, #4}] &, ArcTan[#3, #4] &}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Red, 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> Function[{u, v, x, y}, {x, y}], 
 PlotStyle -> {Opacity[1], 
   Texture[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}]]}]
```

[image]

**Original**
Set `TextureCoordinateFunction -> Function[{x, y, r, s}, {x, y}]`

```
n = 6;
G[z_] = Exp[I Pi/4] Integrate[Power[(1 - (s)^n), -2/n], {s, 0, z}];
ParametricPlot[ReIm[G[r Exp[I s]]], {r, 0, 1}, {s, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Mesh -> {10, 10}, 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> Function[{x, y, r, s}, {x, y}], 
 PlotStyle -> {Opacity[1], 
   Texture[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I tried to use TextureCoordinateFunction, too (without success), but I do not know if this is the right thing to do here. Your code simply puts in the image and cuts the border according to the region _after_ the transformation. What I need is that the picture is transformed as well (as in the first case above).